# How to calculate the correlation of same column value between different group based on another column

Tags: sql, dataframe, correlation

I have a dataframe containing historical stock data looks like this:

| stock_name | price | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stock_a | 35.6 | 2024-01-01 |
| stock_a | 34.7 | 2024-01-02 |
| stock_b | 56.7 | 2024-01-01 |
| stock_b | 55 | 2024-01-02 |

I have multiple stocks in database up to 500, and I want to calculate the correlation between stock_a and all other stocks (ex. stock_b, stock c, stock d...) with their price value across the time interval.

I expect getting the result like:

Stock_A correlation

| stock_name | correlation |
| --- | --- |
| stock_b | 0.87 |
| stock_c | 0.76 |

Now I can only calculate the correlation while specifying each stock other than stock a one by one (PostgreSQL as example):

```
select stock_b, corr(d1.close_price, d2.close_price)
from stock_dmt d1
inner join stock_dmt d2
on d1.time_stamp = d2.time_stamp
where d1.stock_code = 'stock_a' and d2.stock_code = 'stock_b';
```

However it's impossible to do that manually for over 500 stocks.

Is there any efficient way to complete this task? Either with SQL or Python script is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to do with python. I hope this way will meets your question.

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating a sample data
data = {
    "stock_name": ["stock_a", "stock_a", "stock_b", "stock_b"],
    "price": [35.6, 34.7, 56.7,55],
    "time_stamp": ["2024-01-01", "2024-01-02", "2024-01-01", "2024-01-02"]
}

# Create the DataFrame from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert to the pivot table 

df_pivot = df.pivot(index = 'time_stamp',columns=["stock_name"], values="price").reset_index()

# If you can drop the column timestamp 
df_pivot.drop(['time_stamp'], axis = 1).corr()
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for helping, let me try this.
Havnen't use pivot table before.